# Wake up issue on Windows 10 Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS dual boot system

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, grub

If i close the lid on my laptop when it's working either under `Windows` or `Linux` OS and then open the lid, the PC always wakes up and can continue working. But today for some reason, after opening the lid, my PC is either turned off or showing the `Grub 2` menu. The same issue persists under both `Windows` and `Ubuntu` OSs of my dual boot system.
I repaired the `Grub` by means of the `Boot-Repair tool`, however that didn't solve the issue.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Try [Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Comment: Make an additional test under Windows. It is not posible to wake up PC after it goes to sleep even with open lid as it is getting turn off.

Comment: Run *Start > Power Options*, click “Choose what closing the lid does”, set the action (“Do nothing,” “Sleep,” “Hibernate,” or “Shut down”) for “On Battery” and “Plugged in". See [link](https://pureinfotech.com/change-close-lid-action-windows-11/).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that didn't work for me. I tried it today. The issue described in the initial post exists under Ubuntu as well.